emacsclient vs. Chromebook: must manually switch to window
On Linux normally I can do
$ emacsclient --no-wait file.txt

and voila, there I am sitting in emacs editing file.txt before you know it.
But not on ChromeOS Linux. There I need to manually switch to the emacs window by hand.
What would be a one step operation becomes two steps.
If I want a one step operation then I must invoke just plain emacs, not emacsclient.
But then I would have two emacses running.
Rephrasing, on the Chromebook penguin terminal,
emacsclient -n -c file.txt
switches to emacs, but
emacsclient -n -r file.txt
or
emacsclient -n file.txt
needs the user to switch to emacs manually, via ALT TAB.
How do I make it switch automatically? Like on real Linux
Yes, server-raise-frame is t. Changing focus-follows-mouse didn't help.
$ emacsclient --eval "(other-frame 1)"
nil

but I am still left looking at the terminal.
